# Is there any Linux text editor application that supports windows-style KB shortcuts?

Tags: linux, software-rec, editors

I am mainly a Windows user who occasionally uses Linux via ssh terminals.

Currently, I am using `nano` as the text editor.

However, I am so fed up that I am planning to write my own text editor application for Linux using `NCurses`.

Is there any text editor application for Ubuntu that supports Windows-style keyboard shortcuts?

| Aciton | Shortcut |
| --- | --- |
| copy text | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> |
| paste text | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> |
| undo | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> |
| redo | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> |
| select | <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>End</kbd> |
| select all | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> |

Comment: Terminal editors or GUI editors? I think there are a few editors that allow for redefining the keyboard mappings, but in the terminal another issue is selecting the text to cut/copy since mouse integration might well not be possible.

Comment: @ilkkachu, terminal editors.

Comment: Why the downvotes? True there's no obvious research, but it is "useful and clear"

Comment: Windows has been using these keyboard shortcuts for a long time.  Is it possible that no one has written a text mode editor using them in Unix/Linux because keystrokes like Ctrl-C, Ctrl-Z, etc. are used for something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can remap keys in `nano`.

[How can I change the keyboard shortcuts in nano?](https://askubuntu.com/q/235664/473234) over on AskUbuntu